# "Debug Current Instruction Pointer" in setAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have problem when debug my app. I try to create a ListView and when setAdapter then stop. Don't show error or warning on LogCat, only stop the app.This is my code:

```
private ListView List;
private TypedArray Icons;
private ArrayList<MapListItem> mapItems;
private MapListAdapter adapter;

Icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icon_map);
        List = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListMap);
        mapItems = new ArrayList<MapListItem>();
        mapItems.add(new MapListItem(Icons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        mapItems.add(new MapListItem(Icons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        mapItems.add(new MapListItem(Icons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        mapItems.add(new MapListItem(Icons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        mapItems.add(new MapListItem(Icons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        Icons.recycle();
        adapter = new MapListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mapItems);
        List.setAdapter(adapter); //This is pointer error
```

MapListAdapter.java

```
public class MapListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MapListItem> Items;

    public MapListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MapListItem> Items){
        this.context = context;
        this.Items = Items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return Items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_map, null);
        }
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_map);
        imgIcon.setImageResource(Items.get(position).getIcon());        

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

MapListItem.java

```
public class MapListItem {
    private int icon;

    public MapListItem(){}

    public MapListItem(int icon){
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public int getIcon(){
        return this.icon;
    }   
    public void setIcon(int icon){
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

fragment.xml (where is the ListView)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListMap"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#fff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#16a085" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@null">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon_map"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.java

```
public class fragmentMap extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
...
}
```

Why crashed the app ?

Comment: My guess is that List is null. Where is that first block of code, in an Activity or a Fragment? What layout do you inflate and does it contain the id ListMap? Please post a bit more code to illustrate.

Comment: I added XML code, and the code is inside a Fragment the fragment.xml and here is the inflate

Comment: My guess is that the problem is: 'this.getActivity().findViewById'. That is referencing the view hierarchy in the parent Activity, not the one you've inflated in the Fragment. Which View do you inflate and return from onCreateView in the fragment? I think you should be calling findViewById on that.

Comment: the view the inflate and return is fragment.xml, can you make a little example of calling findViewById on that please

Comment: Please post the code in your onCreateView that actually inflates fragment.xml. I'll then (hopefully) be able to post an answer that fits with your actual code. Thx.

Comment: now I put the onCreateView code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is running in a Fragment. Where you have:

```
List = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListMap);
```

that is referencing the view hierarchy you inflated in the parent Activity, not the one you've inflated in the Fragment. In the Fragment, you are inflating fragment.xml into variable 'rootView':

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
return rootView;
```

Therefore you should call findViewById on rootView within your fragment code:

```
List = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListMap);
```

Comment: thx a lot!! Amazing,thank for your patience. I learned a bit more now :D